# Euler Criterion proof

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p\not=2$ be prime, $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\nmid c$. Then $$\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)=c^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$$

---

My attempt:

Let $g\in\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ be the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. So then $c=g^k$ for some $k$. Now let's consider this problem for $g$. Note that

$$g^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}\implies g^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}$$

but note that the order of $g$ is $p-1$ hence

$$g^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv - 1\pmod{p}$$

Then

$$c^{\frac{p-1}2} = \left(g^{\frac{p-1}2}\right)^k \equiv (-1)^k\pmod{p}$$

If $k$ is even then $c$ is a square modulo $p$ hence

$$c^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv1\pmod{p}$$

otherwise $c$ is not a square and hence

$$c^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv-1\pmod{p}$$

Comment: https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/qr.html

Comment: @Arthur the problem there is that he uses $a = g^k$ for some $k$ but $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $g\in\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$.. So it could be the case where $a\not=g^k$.

Comment: Then you just choose a different $k$. It can always be done, that's why they say "Let $g$ be a generator of $\Bbb Z_p^\times$. Any $a\in \Bbb Z^\times_p$ may be written as $g^k$ for some $k$." Of course, the question has now shifted to "Is there a generator for $\Bbb Z^\times_p$?", and they show that [here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/gen.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct but a bit cavalier. Why can you say "otherwise $c$ is not a square"?

The answer to that question is that there are precisely $\frac{p-1}{2}$ squares modulo $p$. Indeed, the map $x \mapsto x^2$ is precisely a two-to-one map (since $x^2 \equiv y^2$ implies $(x+y)(x-y) \equiv 0$, so $p \mid x+y$ or $p \mid x-y$, so $x \equiv \pm y$), so it is immediate that there are precisely half as many squares as there are residues mod $p$.

Since we have found $\frac{p-1}{2}$ squares mod $p$ (namely those $g^{2k}$), the other ones must not be square.

---

My original proof ran as follows:

It is enough to show that the property holds for all $c \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$, because "I am square mod $p$" is a property that is invariant on adding multiples of $p$.

We have $$c^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
and so $$c^{(p-1)/2} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$$

If $c$ is square mod $p$, then $c \equiv a^2 \pmod{p}$, some $a$; as you point out, then we do obtain $1 \pmod{p}$.

But considering all of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, how many solutions have we got there? We've found $\frac{p-1}{2}$ solutions to $$x^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
using a lemma that there are exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues mod $p$ (which can be proved because the map $x \mapsto x^2$ is exactly two-to-one).

So by Lagrange's theorem (which states that in an integral domain, a degree-$d$ polynomial has at most $d$ roots), there are no other roots.
Therefore all the other $a$ must have $$a^{(p-1)/2} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

Comment: Hi, but unfortunately you are only considering $c\in\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. The theorem states for all $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\nmid c$.

Comment: @user2850514 First sentence now says why we can do that.

Comment: Ok. I haven't really covered Lagrange's theorem, I have edited the OP with another attempt. Can you check it's ok?

Comment: I don't like your cavalier statement that if $k$ is odd then $g^k$ is not a square. Granted, $g^k$ is not *obviously* a square, but I would prefer you to prove that it is in fact not square.

Comment: Well if $k=2m-1$ is odd then $g^k=g^{2m-1}$ is clearly not a square. $g$ itself is clearly not a square since it is a generator.

Comment: It's this "clearly" I'm worried about, in both cases. Why must a generator be non-square? Why must an odd power of a non-square also not be square?

Comment: I always thought any odd power of a number is not a square number since it can't be written in the form $(g^\alpha)^2$ where $\alpha$ is an integer. If $g$ is square then $g=h^2$ and therefore $h$ will be the generator which is a contradiction so $g$ must be non-square.

Comment: But there can be (indeed, often is) more than one generator. Why can $h$ not also be a generator?

Comment: Oh right.. I'm not too sure I am not too familiar with group theory, this is just a proof I must learn for my cryptography exam. Is there any way to do this without Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: Added to the top of my answer.